# firefoxadm 0.5.9.3 for firefox9 does not work

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, firefox

I know that [firefoxadm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firefoxadm/) works for old versions of Firefox but it does not for the latest versions. what are people using now, how do you configure for newer versions of firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [Frontmotion's Firefox](http://www.frontmotion.com/Firefox/fmfirefox.htm) package which includes GPO templates. We've just today updated to the latest version of Firefox using this, and everything appears to be working fine.

Comment: i have tried this and the settings work but i have a problem with firefox. i cannot open new tabs once deployed, i have tried firefox ce 9 , 8. if i install by itself, opening tabs work fine.

Comment: Can you disable the policy that holds the configuration (whilst leaving the deployment policy alone)? If this cures it after a `gpupdate /force /boot`, that would suggest the problem is down to one of the settings you've configured in the policy editor.

Comment: i have tried it still does not work. this only occurs on 32bit machines, on 64bit the tabs work fine

Comment: does tabs work for you? what versions have you deployed?

Comment: Frontmotion Firefox 9.0.1 is working perfectly here with GPO templates and tabs. When you state it isn't working, what do you see? Does CTRL-T open a tab or does the 'new tab' icon not appear. Do you get an error message?

Comment: no error messages, i have tried ctrl+t and  using mouse right click and mouse middle scroll and from file menu, i can see the tab but nothing happens when i click on it or try any of the options

Comment: I have also checked about:config and compared it with a normal install and the settings are identical, still the tabs don't work

Comment: Sounds like the Firefox installation could be the problem, rather than the policies. Can you uninstall the package and reinstall it?

Comment: Yes i have tried, i still have the problem.

Comment: what version did you use?

Comment: Sounds very strange, the only thing I can suggest is that maybe you are using a slightly different package to me, and maybe the package you have has a problem. For info, I've used [Firefox-9.0.1-en-GB.msi](http://hicap.frontmotion.com/Firefox/Firefox-9.0.1/Firefox-9.0.1-en-GB.msi). It might be worth asking [here](http://forums.frontmotion.com/)

Comment: thats the same package i am using, which server are you using to deploy? I have asked there but no one has responded as of yet

Comment: We have a Server 2008 R2 domain. The ADM templates I'm using do date back to v4 of firefox IIRC (when I first deployed FMFF), but I don't suspect that TBH. Do you have a clean PC you can install the package onto without any policies?

Comment: I am using same server but domain level is 2003. i am trying fresh install of xp on domain now

Comment: it still does not work even if i just deploy the package and set no policies

Comment: after running a gpresult /v on client machine i have found old firefox settings still being applied under different gpo that i was unaware of, hence once removed firefox worked

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved it.

Comment: I have noticed that on 32bit machines if i disable ipv6 it messes up the tabs on firefox version greater than 3.x.  As i use a proxy to access the internet. the js is run at startup which disables ipv6  since js picks up the ipv6 in firfox if it is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Also, consider using the [Autoconfig feature](http://mit.edu/~firefox/www/maintainers/autoconfig.html) that is built into Firefox if you need something that's more flexible (at the expense of complexity of course).

Comment: A link to Mozilla's Autoconfig information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/MCD,_Mission_Control_Desktop_AKA_AutoConfig

Comment: I use Autoconfig for 300+ machines, great tool and option.

Comment: can anyone show any how to guides on this?

does the autoconfig feature support single sign on.. ntlm or ntld i think it is called not sure

Comment: @sharif Single-sign-on for what exactly? Proxy access?

Comment: intranet login.